# Whatsapp Chat not sorted chronologically after a message delete

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Previously when I used to delete a message from a chat, Whatsapp automatically use to resort the chat list according to date. Starting for last week, when I delete a message, it does not change the chat list by date. For example, if someone messaged me last month and then again today, if I delete today's message, his chat will not move down to last month. In fact, it will remain on top of the list with last month date on the right.
But if I do the same action from the Whatsapp Web, all is working as expected.

Also, in another phone I do not have the "undo delete message for me" option, and the behaviour is as expected.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp fixed this issue with the release 2.23.1.76 for Android.