# WhatsApp chats are not sorted chronologically

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra. Starting today, my WhatsApp chats are not sorted chronologically. When a new message comes in, it's supposed to display at the top of the chat list, but that's not happening.

The only solution I've found so far is to force-stop the app, and then the chats are sorted correctly. However, if I receive a new message after that, it won't sort automatically again

Could you please let me know if this issue has been sorted out? If yes, please share the trick with me.

Comment: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have a similar question [WhatsApp chat not sorted chronologically after a message delete](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249555/44325) but it's quite old (Dec 2022)

Comment: Is this for all chats or just a few?  Is it for group chats and personal chats?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @RohitGupta, Ys its applicable for all chats.  Suppose someone had sent a message two weeks ago, and today, if he sends another message, his name is supposed to come to the top, but it's not happening.